# current_user_can capabilities in the admin not working as expected

Tags: capabilities

I'm trying to block admin dashboard access using `wp_redirect()`.

But the results of using `current_user_can('edit_post')` are unexpected.

See my complete function below...

```
/**
 * user constructor method.
 */
public function __construct()
{

    // block admin dashboard access
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this , 'block_admin_access' ) );

}

/**
 * block admin dashboard access to users who cant edit posts
 */
public function block_admin_access () {

    // if users cannot edit posts
    if( ! current_user_can('edit_post') ) {

        // redirect user to home page
        wp_redirect( get_home_url() );

    }

}
```

When I am logged in as an administrator user, this code above blocks me from the dashboard. Administrators can definately edit posts, so why does this code above redirect me away from the dashboard?

When I am using `current_user_can('edit_post')` on the front end, the behaviour is normal.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: which user as you logged in ?

Comment: As a administrator

Comment: is redirect to the home url or not ?

Comment: Yes, it is the wp_redirect that its hitting

Comment: Have you tried checking against `edit_posts` plural?

Comment: @WebElaine Ahhh you're right! Can't believe I didn't see that. I feel really silly now. Thank you!

Comment: thanks @WebElaine. i can't see that dude thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

With you `current_user_can` call everything is just fine. The problem lies elsewhere...

If you'll take a look at [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), you'll see that there is no capability like `edit_post`. So your code is working correctly - admin can't `edit_post`, because there is no such capability (unless it's a custom capability registered by your code elsewhere).

But my gut tells me that you wanted to check if current user can `edit_posts` ;)